# How to sort array numbers high to low in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

It is array:

```
$a = rand(1,100);
$b = rand(1,100);
$c = rand(1,100);
$arr =  array($a ,$b , $c);
```

I want to  sort generated numbers high to low.

Comment: arsort($arr); http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Comment: Quickly, is it an examination?

Comment: I've downvoted for the begging in the title - we try to discourage that sort of behaviour here.

Answer (score 2):

Sort Array (Descending Order), According to Value - arsort()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
arsort($age);

foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
Key=Joe, Value=43
Key=Ben, Value=37
Key=Peter, Value=35
```

Comment: I hope so this is what you need bro from the Question which you posted. Are you getting output as requested by you. :)

Comment: Have you obtained the output @Норайр..

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
rsort($arr);
```

[PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use arsort():  [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_arsort.asp)

```
    print_r(arsort($arr));
```

Sort an associative array in descending order, according to the value:

Comment: I  need  and  sorting , and  printing values  in  display , but  when  I 'm  sorting  and  displaying , code  write  in  display  1

Comment: print_r(arsort($arr)); do something like this @Норайр

Answer (score 0):

```
Use 
$sort = arsort($arr);
print_r()
```